# How can I run a MONO application/program on boot?

Tags: boot, mono

I would like to make this as userfriendly as possible, so my MONO application is going to be a fullscreen application that runs automatically when the OS and startx is done loading.

How do I run a MONO.exe on startup?

Comment: have you written the application already?

Comment: but ofcause - no I have written a simple Monotest.exe that I will see if I can run on boot, because this would open up a lot of possibilities for me regarding development and usage.

Comment: @abolotnov - I dont expect it to take me long to write the first "fullscreen" application, once I figure out where to put the bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can add a line to ~/.xinitrc

```
mono programName parameters_if_any
```

this will get executed eacht time startx is called.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found the correct answer now.

You can use something called "mono-service" to run programs in the background or you can place the program in the boot scripts.

All you need is to call the program with either mono-service [program path and name] or mono [program path and name]

Answer (score 1):

You can use "mono-service" to run programs in the background.

You can run your compiled code like so:

```
mono-service /home/pi/Desktop/StartBrowser.exe
```

By default, this creates a lockfile in /tmp. You can change this by using the -l: option. In this way your service is running in the background

Comment: okay, that sounds cool too, gotta try that at some point. Thanks